# Animated buffergeometry with morphattributes not updating shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I have converted the MD2 code from the library to use `THREE.BufferGeometry` instead of `THREE.Geometry` to vastly improve memory footprint. To do this I just convert the model to `THREE.BufferGeometry` after it is done loading. I also had to modify the `MorphBlendMesh` code to use attributes for the `morphTargetInfluences`.

This is working great except for issue: the shadows don't update during animation, it always uses the shadow from the first frame of the animation.

I haven't seen any documentation on `morphTargetInfluences` attributes, so I don't have much to go on.

I can't really post the code since it is too much spread out across the code base.

I am just hoping that someone out there might have some insight as to how shadows get updated during morph animation, and maybe point me in the right direction on how to research this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, and a workaround!

The code in the shader renderer is checking to see if `geometry.morphTargets` has a non-zero length before it decides to set the `'usemorphing'` flag.  The converted buffergeometry does not have a `.morphTargets` field since this information appears to have moved to `.morphAttributes` for buffergeometries.

My hack workaround is to add a fake `.morphTarget` list like so:

```
Buffergeometry.morphTargets = [];
Buffergeometry.morphTargets.push(0);
```